# Can I use "contains" logic in categories?

Tags: categories

Is there a way to say "If this entry *contains* category 5" rather than "If this entry's category is category 5"?

Consider this:

```
{categories}
{if category_id="5"}
Do something
{/if}
{/categories}
```

I believe the condition would only return true of the *only* category assigned is category 5. If an entry has categories 5 and 6 assigned, it would not be returned here, but that's what I'm looking for.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to only DO Something for the entries belong to category(id=5) your code will do the trick but if u use "show" param the code will be better:

```
{categories show="5"}
Do something
{/categories}
```

but If u want to Do Something for the entries belong to category(id=5) and another Thing for the entries don't belong to category(id=5) try to use:

```
{categories show="5"}
Do something
{/categories} 
{categories show="not 5"}
Do Another thing
{/categories}
```

I hope this will do the trick.

Regard's.

Comment: But isn't the value of the category for an entry with categories 5 and 6 assigned to it "56" and therefore not 5?

Comment: No , we you assigned entry to category this will add a new row to exp_category_posts(entry_id,cat_id) columns, category values is a multi row values so EE use it as a tag pair.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken your code should do exactly that.

It would find 5 in the loop and 'do something' and then loop again at 6 and do nothing because there's nothing to execute.

May not be especially efficient but should work.